# How to change the style of a text if a button is clicked based on table row data in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a code in **jquery**. My problem is, how to put strike-through 
in a row containing "101". each number, is stored in a table.

example input:

<strike>1   0   1</strike>  1  <strike>1 0 1</strike>

those data are stored in a table. Now I want to cancel, (using strike through), all td which contains 101 in a combination.

```
<style>

td.cancel:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
 }
 tr.cancel td:before {
   content: " ";
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
   width: 100%;
  }
</style>`

<table id="myTable">
   <tr> 
      <td>1</td><!-- row1, col1 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- row1, col2 -->
      <td>1</td><!-- row1, col3 -->
      <td>1</td><!-- row1, col4 -->
      <td>1</td><!-- row1, col5 -->
      <td>0</td><!-- row1, col6 -->
      <td>1</td><!-- row1, col7 -->
   </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="btn">
```

The idea is similar to the SOS game. Does anybody know?

Comment: What should happen if you have this in a row: 1  1  1  0  1  0  1 ? I guess that just first ('whole') sequence should be striked-through?

Comment: "*I am trying to create a code in [jQuery]*" - how far did you get, where did you get stuck, what help do you need, where are your attempts so far?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to retrieve the textual values held within the `tr` to a single string and then loop through that to find pattern matches. When a match is found you can amend the `td` based on the index of the matching characters in the string, something like the below.

I'm sure there are more efficient ways, but this should get you started.

```js
var pattern = '101';

$('button').click(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '');
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.length - pattern.length; i++) {
      var end = i + pattern.length;
      if (text.substring(i, end) == pattern) 
        $(this).find('td').slice(i, end).addClass('pattern-match');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pattern-match {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #C00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn">Find matches</button>
```

Comment: Made something similar, with same results, less elegant,though :), just not sure that this is desired output: https://jsfiddle.net/rcexwz1m/ when patterns are 'mixed' (check second row) -> starting '1' of second sequence is ending '1' of first sequence in the same time...